# bootstrap html css tabs not taking up full width of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

template url
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/33Rxn

I have been trying to edit this template take up the full width of the screen but i cant get it to. I have tried commenting out all of the "width" attributes in the CSS but it is still not taking full width of browser.

Comment: Post your html code  .. please

Answer (score 1):

```
try change 

<div class="container">
```

with

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
```

or change the with for class  container in css

eg building a proper full container

```
.container-fullwidth {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I suggest the first approach, if you have included the bootstrap library might as well make use of it rather than re-writing custom code when its already provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new css rule for the container class, and edit the 75% width of the board class to be 100%, inside the css tab of the bootsnip.

```
.container {
  width:100%;
}
.board{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 60px auto;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
 /*box-shadow: 10px 10px #ccc,-10px 20px #ddd;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes the class of first div to container-fluid and set the width inside the board class to 100%

```
<div class="container"> to <div class="container-fluid">
.board { width: 75%; } to .board { width: 100%; }
```